# connect to a distant data base using python

Tags: python, mysql

Running this command in the terminal with the correct values I get connected and can read the data base:

```
mysql -h mysql.lyon...fr -u user --password=passworld
```

I have to do this in a python script, I tried few functions like:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql

print '======================================================================================'
print 'Connextion to the database'
print '======================================================================================'
# mysql -h mysql.lyon....fr -u XXuser --password=XXpasswd

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect(host='mysql....grid5000.fr'  , user='XXuser', passwd='XXpasswdread oar2')
```

```
======================================================================================
Connextion to the database
======================================================================================

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "process.py", line 14, in <module>
        con = mdb.connect(host='mysql.lyon......fr'  , user='user name ', passwd='......')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
        return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
        super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'oarreader'@'flyon.lyon.grid5000.fr' (using password: YES)")
```

How can I define the arguments in the connect function to connect to the server knowing its address?

Comment: Add the part of code segment that you used for establishing connection so that others can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the same user that in the terminal, in the terminal you use -u user and using python you use oarreader

Comment: no i m using the correct ones just modifed them now,

Comment: mysql -h mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr -u the user --password=the paasword
 
con = mdb.connect(host='mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr'  , user=' the user name', passwd='the  password')

is that correct ?

Comment: The Access denied for user 'oarreader'@'flyon.lyon.grid5000.fr' (using password: YES) error is clear. That user doesnt have permissions. Can you show us the code how you try to connect with python?

Comment: Dont you need the database name? Something like this conn = mdb.connect('ip_address', 'user_name', 'pass_word', 'database_name')

Comment: in the terminal i just use :
mysql -h mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr -u the user --password=the paasword
and get connected 

now in python I write 
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(host='mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr'  , user=' the user' name', passwd='the  password')

is that correct ?

Comment: in the terminal i just use :
mysql -h mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr -u the user --password=the paasword
and get connected 

now in python I write 
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(host='mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr'  , user=' the user' name', passwd='the  password')

is that correct to use host and put the link not the ip @ ? I can't find other options

Comment: That should work, the options are fine, you just are not connecting to a specific database... how are you executing the python? is a python script in the same machine you tested the connection trough command line?

Comment: Well is indeed strange, I see in your traceback you try to connect to flyon.lyon.grid5000.fr notice the 'f' before lyon and in your command line your host begins with "mysql..." host='mysql....grid5000.fr' have you double checked your parameters?

Comment: the database is in lyon site , so i connect to lyon then run the commmand mysql and i  see the data base , now i just put the script and on the same level i run the script but i got that error, am I missing something ??

Comment: You connect to lyon site through ssh? so using localhost as host would work as well?

Comment: # mysql -h mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr -u yyy --password=xxxx

con = mdb.connect(host='mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr'  , user='yyy', passwd='xxx', db='oar2')

Comment: using localhost I got this 

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

Comment: What about the db oar2? you are not using that through the command line. Is it working in the command line? mysql -u yyy -pxxxx -h mysql.lyon.grid5000.fr oar2

Comment: yes i connect to first grid5000 through ssh then lyon also with ssh